# Clone input elements and clear values after

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code to clone elements:

```
$(this).prevAll("span:last").clone().insertBefore($(this));
```

But input's are cloned with previous values and I don't want that. I tried this:

```
$(this).prevAll("span:last").clone().insertBefore($(this)).val("");
```

But isn't working, can any give me some help? How do I clone the element but with clear values?

Comment: You are cloning spans, is the input inside the span?

Comment: @Anton yes, input are inside the span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.find()`

```
$(this).prevAll('span:last').clone().find('input').val('').insertBefore($(this))
```

Comment: It works but I added some tweaks to your code `$(this).prevAll('span:last').clone().insertBefore($(this)).find('input').val('');` since I need to create the input inside span